# Can we automate the conversational flow of a chatbot?

Tags: automation, chatbot

Is there a way to automate the conversational flow of chatbot? i.e., testing a conversation between the chatbot and end user.

I have been working in testing a chatbot. And doing Research on automation tools or practices available for testing the chatbot.

no code available. have been working on ready available tool botium box.

Comment: have you tried something like: https://chatbotsmagazine.com/5-steps-automated-testing-of-chatbots-in-eclipse-ef4c3dcaf233

Answer (score 0):

Botium Box is exactly for automated testing of the conversational flow of a chatbot.

Here is the “Hello, World!” of Botium for testing a simple two-step conversation (question - response):

```
#me
hello bot!

#bot
Hello, meat bag! How can I help you ?
```

You can do the same in an Excel file as well, it looks like this:
[image]

For further lecture, I recommend the [Botium in a Nutshell](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-1-overview-f8d0ceaf8fb4) blog series, and the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/overview)